# GStreamer, merging 4 streams into one and restream

Tags: windows-7, merge, streaming, gstreamer, rtsp

I'm trying to read 4 ip cameras at once and then merge them into one mosaic video and restream it to the client. So far, I managed to receive 4 streams and display mosaic but can't figured out what to do next.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
videomixer name=mix \
        sink_0::xpos=0   sink_0::ypos=0  sink_0::alpha=0\
        sink_1::xpos=0   sink_1::ypos=0 \
        sink_2::xpos=640 sink_2::ypos=0 \
        sink_3::xpos=0   sink_3::ypos=360 \
        sink_4::xpos=640 sink_4::ypos=360 \
    ! autovideosink \
videotestsrc pattern="black" \
    ! video/x-raw,format=AYUV,width=1280,height=720 \
    ! mix.sink_0 \
uridecodebin uri=rtsp://10.0.0.121:554/video.h264 \
    ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
    ! video/x-raw,format=AYUV,width=640,height=360 \
    ! mix.sink_1 \
uridecodebin uri=rtsp://10.0.0.122:554/video.h264 \
    ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
    ! video/x-raw,format=AYUV,width=640,height=360 \
    ! mix.sink_2 \
uridecodebin uri=rtsp://10.0.0.123:554/video.h264 \
    ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
    ! video/x-raw,format=AYUV,width=640,height=360 \
    ! mix.sink_3 \
uridecodebin uri=rtsp://10.0.0.124:554/video.h264 \
    ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
    ! video/x-raw,format=AYUV,width=640,height=360 \
    ! mix.sink_4 \
```

I'm using latest Gstreamer on Win7. Any advices would be appreciated!

Comment: What type of stream are you trying to create?

Comment: I have for IP cameras with h264 video via rtsp protocol. What I need to do is create mosaic of those videos and restream it via rtsp as one stream to the client app. Can You help me somehow?

Comment: You'll need to first encode the video, probably with the x264enc plugin.  If RTSP is what you have to use for the streaming, you'll want to investigate gst-rtsp-server.  I don't have a one-liner for you though for RTSP.

Comment: Actually to just play video I dont need to encode but for restreaming maybe. My problem is that for using rtsp server i need to write it down to a code and compile rtsp server which I am not able to do for now. Any help with that?

Comment: You'll have to re-encode for sure because you're creating a new image.

Comment: Probably you're right but for now I need to write code and compile it with rtsp server ...

Answer (score -1):

If you're willing to use RTP instead of RTSP you can use something like this.

Sender:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e \
videomixer name=mix \
 sink_0::xpos=0   sink_0::ypos=0 \
 sink_1::xpos=640   sink_1::ypos=0 \
 ! queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! h264parse ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=localhost port=5200 \
videotestsrc \
 ! video/x-raw,format=AYUV,width=640,height=360 \
 ! mix.sink_0 \
videotestsrc pattern="ball" \
 ! videoconvert ! videoscale \
 ! video/x-raw,format=AYUV,width=640,height=360 \
 ! mix.sink_1 \
```

Receiver:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5200 ! \
application/x-rtp,media=video,payload=96,encoding-name=H264 ! \
rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! \
videoconvert ! ximagesink
```

Comment: Unfortunetly I need RTSP protocol. Aby ideas so I could write it into a code and what is more to compile RTSP Server on Windows machine? Best would be some sort of "how to" on visual studio

Comment: It's outside of my domain, sorry.  I'd suggest looking into gst-rtsp-server.

Comment: tell me, can you help me somehow with rewriting my oneliner into C code?

Comment: Will this work in Windows machine. I tried in Windows 7 machine. Unfortunately doesn't work for me :(